# Interior Sliding Door Latch or Snib, openable from both sides

Tags: interior, latches

I'm looking for a interior sliding door latch or snib that can be released and engaged from boths sides.

I've been unable to find such a piece of hardware, it should not be lockable. Each item I have found has the opening mechanisim on one side only.

Has anyone seen such an item. (Also looking for the Australian term for it if known)

Thanks

Comment: Take a suitable sliding latch and add a second handle that pokes through a slot in the door. May have to drill and tap the hole to get a good fixing for the extended handle.

Comment: I've considered this, even buying two and replacing the non-handled side with the handle from the second unit.

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with a few door specialist stores for doors. I had to settle for buying two privacy sets and latch mechanisim to allow for opening/unlatching on both sides of the sliding door.

(Each specialist was perplexed they did'nt actually have a product to cover this situation.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in Aus and I'm in the US, our search results may be a bit different, but I did a simple DuckDuckGo search for "interior sliding door latch".

Scrolling past the "shopping" recommendations (as is my habit), the first result was for Amazon.com listing their "best sellers". Nothing there came up, so I searched for "interior sliding door latch" on Amazon.com. The 1st item listed was a lockable latch. Scrolling down to the "related items", I found this [sliding door pull](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009E1Z1O6). It's a single item that goes all the way through the door and has a detent on either side.

The second DDG result that I looked at took me to Home Depot listing for a [rectangular finger pull](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-3-1-4-in-Solid-Brass-with-Satin-Nickel-Finish-Rectangular-Finger-Pull-2-Pack-N-7342/202258390). This is a pair of detents that are installed back-to-back in the door so you can pull it from either side.

(IMHO, the single unit would be easier to install since it's one cutout all the way through the door instead of making two depressions, one on either side, and trying to get them to line up. But, we're not here for my opinion...)

You may want to search for either a "sliding door pull" or a "rectangular finger pull" at your local retailer/web-site. If that doesn't work, print out the two images, take it to your local retailer and "point and grunt". ;)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately these are non latching. I already have the pulls, the latch is to actually stop our dogs from sliding the door open. So we need it openable (un-latching) from boths sides. I spoke to the rep at Bunnings (Australias Home Depot) and they either could not understand what I was saying or had never heard of one. I'm even looking through baby lock mechanisms that might work.

Comment: My apologies, @jezr74, I misread that and didn't realize you wanted them to latch from both sides. Your darn Australian Sheep Dogs are way too clever if they can open a sliding door! I'm glad our dog is just a cute, dumb mutt. :)

Comment: Ha, all good it's one of those items I just assumed existed and would be common that is appearing to not be.